# Check In Through Facebook SDK 4.5.0

Tags: android, android-facebook

How could I check in using latest `Facebook SDK 4.5.0`. I got a solution using older SDK.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("access_token", "YOUR ACCESS TOKEN");
params.putString("place"`enter code here`, "203682879660695");  // YOUR PLACE ID
params.putString("message","I m here in this place");

JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
coordinates.put("latitude", "YOUR LATITUDE");
coordinates.put("longitude", "YOUR LONGITUDE");

params.putString("coordinates",coordinates.toString());
params.putString("tags", "xxxx");//where xx indicates the User Id

String response = faceBook.request("me/checkins", params, "POST");

Log.d("Response",response);
```

The same I want using latest Facebook SDK.

Comment: Where you stuck mam ?

Comment: Thanks to Reply @andi,I need a code that can check in using latest SDK.